# Planning VHD-based laptop install

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, windows-8-preview, vhd, boot-to-vhd

I am about to take delivery of a new laptop with a 750GB HDD.  I will be using Win7 as the base OS (as a "real" installation, direct to the tin).  The base install will probably have Visual Studio installed for dev work.

I also want to add 2 bootable VHDs, one for a "fresh" win 7 install (allocating about 128GB), and an install of the preview of Win 8 (about 100GB).

I would also like (if possible - I'm not sure if it is) I'd like to allocate a chunk of disk (probably a separate partition - maybe 100GB) as a shared data drive.

My questions are :

1. Can I have a shared partition that is avaiable to all the OSs by creating a separate partition?
2. What is the best order to install VHD OSs?  I'm thinking 7 then 8 to take advantage of the W8 boot Manager
3. Should I go the whole hog and install my dev instance of Win7 in a VHD as well, and do away with a base "on the tin" install?
4. Are there any pitfalls to this approach that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had almost this exact configuration in the past and with the first Windows 8 developer preview that came out in 2011. I even had Ubuntu over the top of everything, I ended up trusting Grub boot manager to ensure everything was fine. But it all worked fine at the step before Ubuntu was installed.

1. A shared partition should work fine.
2. Install Windows 7 first, and configure Windows 8 VHD next (I suggest this approach because it has worked for me, and for [Scott Hanselman in this guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx).
3. No. Have an "on the tin" Windows 7. Remember the VHDs you have can be backed up fine and re-added to the same laptop without worry if you have to re-pave the base Windows 7 install. Unless you really need to access all the files on the host OS from with the VHDs.
4. Size allocations if you go the 'fixed' size allocation of the VHDs, I had to spend some effort it re-sizing the VHDs when it got to the point where the 40 or 50Gb I had allocated got all used up.

Also your 100+ gig allocations sound reasonable. I did all this on the 500Gb HD and struggled a little. Host OS, 2 VHDs, Ubuntu, (no shared partition).